# why some service are lazy while start running jboss server

Tags: java, jboss, server, jboss-eap-6

The message below indicates that JBoss did not start 59 services out of 299. Why is that?

> INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP
>   6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) started in 10290ms - Started 261 of 299 services (59 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

Answer (score 2):

This is because JBoss starts certain subsystems/services only when needed. This makes the initial boot process faster as well as save memory.

Certain services such as clustering is not needed until you actually deploy an application that requires clustering (for example, your application has the `<distributable />` tag in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file). So when this particular application is deployed and you are using a "HA" profile to start JBoss, it will automatically start JBoss clustering related services.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons of this, I have faced a similar issue few days back. I am going to tell you what helped in my case.
The issue was that the folder in which the jboss was kept has a space character in the name.

Eg. D:/**New Folder**/Jboss/jboss-eap-6.3

This was somehow creating an issue, after several hit and trials after we moved the same jboss instance to another folder, and then it no longer showed any lazy services.

So make sure you do not keep your server with such a folder name.